# How to keep vertex colors generated with geometry nodes when exporting to .FBX?

Tags: export, geometry-nodes, .fbx, vertex-colors

I'm trying to export a mesh with vertex colors generated by geometry nodes but when I export it, it comes out with 100% in all channels.

Here's the solution I'm trying to make it work:

1. Make geometry node spit out a color attribute
   [image]
2. Make the Geometry node in the Modifier stack output the attribute to the "Col" vertex color attribute
   [image]
3. Check results - looks as expected in rendered viewport!
   [image: List item]
4. Export as .FBX and import into Unity and compare to a mesh exported with manually painted vertex colors.
   [image: Compare image]
5. This is the step where I realise it doesnt work. No clue why it doesn't work.

Things I have tried to make it work:

- Applying all Modifiers in the modifier stack prior to exporting the .FBX
- Using the "Make all instances real", just to be sure - but I don't think I'm using any instance.
- Importing the .FBX into Blender again to double check the vert colors are the same as in Unity (which they are)
- Praying to the Blender gods

Anyone know what I'm missing? I'm quite sure the geometry node doesn't "apply" the vertex color prior to export giving me the result of default vertex colors (which means 100% colored) but I have no clue on how to apply/bake it.

Please help!

Comment: although i am not an fbx expert, but what i read about it i would say: fbx does not support vertex color generated by blender. So i would guess you would have to bake an image texture from your material and use that

Comment: Hello @Chris thanks for input!

Well the thing is I have already got an FBX with vertex painted successfully exported with vertex colors - it's just that I can't get the vertex colors to work with vertex colors generated by geometry nodes.

Comment: Ok, then ignore my comment 

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using *Face Corner* for *Attribute Domain*. It will default to *Point* which is incorrect.

They changed things up recently so I know this works in 3.1 but I'm not sure in 3.2.

[image]