# Exporting vertex colors made with geometry nodes in .FBX for Unreal engine

Tags: geometry-nodes, export, .fbx, vertex-colors

I'm having trouble exporting vertex colors which I assigned via geometry nodes. The advice given in these posts: [How to export vertex colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272054/how-to-export-vertex-colors) , [How to keep vertex colors generated with geometry nodes when exporting to .FBX?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264902/how-to-keep-vertex-colors-generated-with-geometry-nodes-when-exporting-to-fbx) does not work for me this time, although it did work on an earlier attempt on an older version of blender, so perhaps this is verison related. I am on 3.6.1 now

Vertex color is displayed correctly in blender for me [image]

I've set the attribute domain to Face Corner [image]

But the vertex colors made using geometry nodes do not import to external softwares

Vertex colors that I painted in vertex paint mode do however export correctly [image]

And I can assign the attribute as vertex color if I reimport the .FBX to blender, so the attribute is being exported, just not in a way that external softwares can recognise. Any ideas on how to fix this?